# changes when back to Read Only Mode in form View asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I'm using asp.net with c#. I want to update data Form View and it works fine. 
The problem is when I click on update button and back to Read Only Mode, the other content of page are shifted to the left and the data of form view goes smaller!. how can I avoid this changes?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As a start please read [FAQ] and [ask]. Show your work also..

Comment: Add Some Code what you had tried...

Comment: I fixed this problem by using Ajax. Thanks